# command button run time exception

Tags: vb.net, excel, exception

I have a sample code for creating button in an excel sheet vb.net code as follows:

```
Dim button As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.OLEObject
button = _xlWorksheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
   Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=100, Height:=30)
button.Name = "Send Mail"

Dim oCommandBar As Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBar
Dim oCommandBarButton As Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarControl
Dim tb As String = "My Toolbar"
Dim _btnCaption As String = "Forward To BSC"
'Dim code As String

'code = "Sub button_Click()" & vbCrLf
'code = code & "Call Tester" & vbCrLf
'code = code & "End Sub"

Try
   oCommandBar = _xlApp.CommandBars.Add(.......) 

   'oCommandBar = _xlApp.CommandBars.Add(.....)
   oCommandBar.Visible = True

   oCommandBarButton = oCommandBar.Controls.Add(button)
   oCommandBarButton.Caption = _btnCaption
   oCommandBarButton.OnAction = "button_Click"
Catch ex As Exception
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try

 Sub Tester()
      MsgBox("You have click on the test button")
 End Sub
```

I am not sure what to add in the following:
`_xlApp.CommandBars.Add(.......) and _xlApp.CommandBars.Add(.....)`

Please advise. Also specify namespaces required. This is a in a console app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your issue, however:
the code adds a new command bar in the bars collections.
The syntax is something like this: CommandBars.Add("MyTemporaryToolbar", _
 MsoBarPosition.msoBarTop, False, True); 
For more infos maybe following articles will be useful to you: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861773.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17458/Adding-commandbar-controls-to-outlook